# Average of a two dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hey I got an array "a" which looks like this:

```
[[5], [7], [8]] # result of "puts a.to_s"
```

How can I calculate the average of the array.
I already have a method that works for normal arrays with one dimension:

```
def average
 return self.reduce(:+)/self.length.to_f
end
```

How can I convert the array from above in a normal array or how to use that method for the more dimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array#flatten` you can use your predefined average method.